# Target detection for UAV landing

Tags: image-processing, detection

I would like to detect and track the following target to land an UAV. Target size is $1\rm m \times 1\rm m$.

[image: Target]

I have tried SIFT + FLANN but there is too few keypoints to have a good match.

Have you any idea on which algorithm I should use ?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! For your application, what constitutes a "good match" ? I'm assuming you need scale, shift, and shear invariance? Is the background green there always? Or just the black and white?

Comment: Thanks ! A good match would be to acquire target's center regardless of scale, shift and shear. The target is "designed" as follow : big squares for detection when uav is high and little squares for precision landing.
Green background represents grass on the ground so it may change.